# How to stop redirection via exec

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, exec

I want to redirect some output of a script to a file.

```bash
REDIRECT_FILE="foo.txt"

echo to console

# starting redirect
exec > $REDIRECT_FILE

echo to file
echo ...
echo ...

# stop redirect
exec >&-

echo end of script
```

"end of script" should be written to stdout.
But instead there is a "Bad file descriptor" error message.

`exec 1>&-` does not work too.

What is the correct term to stop the redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exec 1>&-` closes *stdout*. It doesn't revert it to the original value because you'd already replaced that with `exec > $REDIRECT_FILE` (which should be `exec > "$REDIRECT_FILE"` to protect the variable's value from any further processing by by the shell).

To revert *stdout* to its original value you need to save it

```
exec 3>&1                  # Save stdout as FD 3
exec 1>"$REDIRECT_FILE"    # Redirect stdout to a file
…
exec 1>&3                  # Revert stdout to its original value
```

Comment: Thanks! - Should I close "&3" after revert stdout? (add `exec 3>&-` at the end of the script)

Comment: No need - the descriptions will all be cleaned up when the process exits